# How to make div fade in/out on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

Need some advice: I'm looking to create a fadeIn/fadeOut script that works responsively as the page scrolls. What I want to do:

- on scroll, once it gets to a hidden div, it fades in.
- once scroll reaches the top of the page, it fades out.
- any future scrolls have the div fade in and out, as it appears/disappears.

Here's a sample code that creates the fadein, but only does it once. I need it to fade in and out each time it is triggered.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

    });

    });
```

Any advice?

Thanks, and I hope that made sense!

Comment: added code I have to comment

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered jQuery Waypoints? It's a plugin that allows you to execute functions whenever you scroll to an element.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

You can then execute a .fadeIn() on that element when you scroll to it.

Comment: I have seen Waypoints, but I'm not 100% sure how to implement it. My jquery skills are quite basic.